# How to configure windows server with ansible using YAML

Tags: ansible, yaml

- How to turn off IE enhanced security using ansible
- Is there any way I can configure user account in Windows server by using  ansible YAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with powershell:

myscript.ps1:

```
$AdminKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
$UserKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $AdminKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path $UserKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 0
Stop-Process -Name Explorer
```

Ansible playbook:

```
- name: example copying file with owner and permissions
  copy:
    src: myscript.ps1
    dest: myscript.ps1

- name: Run ps1 script in privileged mode
  hosts: "{{ my_hosts }}"
  become_method: runas

  vars:
    ansible_become_password: passwordhere

  tasks:
    - win_shell: '.\myscript.ps1'
      become: yes
      become_user: Administrator

- name: Create new user
  win_user:
    name: someuser
    password: somepassword
    state: present
    groups:
      - Users
```